# If password in textbox doesn't match databases', stop FORM from submitting

Tags: php, jquery

In the update password form, if the `current password` is not same as what is there in the database how should I stop the form from submitting?

Presently, I have a form wherein using AJAX I am checking if the password in the textbox is same as that in the database and if not, it displays a message that password is incorrect but when I submit the form with a new password, the password gets updated.

I want that if password in textbox is not the same as is present in the database, execution should stop until correct password is not entered.

`FORM`

```html
 <h5>Update Password</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content nopadding">
              <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" name="password_validate" id="password_validate" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Current Password</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="current_pwd" id="current_pwd" />
                    <span id="chk_pwd"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label">New Password</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="new_pwd" id="new_pwd" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="confirm_pwd" id="confirm_pwd" />
                    <span id="chk_confirm_pwd"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Validate" class="btn btn-success">
                </div>
              </form>
```

`JQUERY`

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#new_pwd').click(function(){
                var current_pwd=$('#current_pwd').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type:'get',
                    url:'admin_profile_settings_back.php',
                    data:{current_pwd:current_pwd},
                    //dataType:"html",
                    success:function(resp){
                     $("#chk_pwd").html(resp).show().fadeOut(3000);
                     
                 }
                })
            })
        })
```

`PHP Backend for AJAX`

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include "../includes/config.php";
 
 
    $current_pwd=$_GET['current_pwd'];
    $aid=$_SESSION['aid'];
    
    $r=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE aid='$aid' ");
    $row=$r->fetch_assoc();
    
    if($current_pwd==$row['password'])
    {
        echo "Password Is Correct";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Password Is Incorrect";
    }
```

Comment: So, you have cleartext passwords in your database? That's not so good, you should rather check if the submitted password has the same hash as the one you have saved before. So don't stop the submission, just return with an error in case the hashes don't match (and ofcourse, don't update at that time)

Comment: HTTP is request/response based. You could at the outside perform two subsequent requests, checking the password first, then sending a huge amount of data (providing the password or another secret again for sequrity reasons). Call `password_verify` using stored hashes.

Comment: @Icepickle Presently I am not working for a production environment which is why I am not using Hashes. I am storing the passwords as varchar and want to stop execution in case password and database entry doesn't match.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I am not storing the passwords as Hashes right now.

Comment: That doesn't change anything in the workflow. Requesting the password for verification before the form can be submitted, is imho not a good way to go about it, it is rather giving a way that people can verify a certain password instead. it would be lots better to let the user submit the form instead, and then return a failure as a result of the action to say that it couldn't be updated because the passwords don't match, or to update the password in case they do match. Production environment or not, why not go at it correctly from the start ;)

Comment: @Icepickle I had an idea that on the client side if `current password` doesn't match with the database, throw an error using Jquery. In similar fashion, if `new password` doesn't match with the `confirm password`, using `validate()`, throw an error and stop execution. But the only problem I am facing is how to compare the data fetched from database with the one in the `current password` textbox?

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks anyways, you gave me a nice idea though, I think your way is quite simple and I would like to go with it until I find a solution to the way I want to execute my idea.

Comment: *"I am not storing the passwords as Hashes right now"* Exactly this is one of your problems. Check the password on login and again when attempting to perform security relevant actions. OnSubmit you can verify the password via AJAX before starting a huge transmission. The password verification should take 1-2 seconds generating a hash and comparing it.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Got your point, thanks a lot.

Comment: Again, do not store plain passwords, use `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions setting an appropriate cost of calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should include a where clause to check for the current password.
2. You should hash + salt your password
3. This example does not have any input checks, you should always verify user input, ALWAYS.
4. You should use the PDO library and perform prepare statements, is more secure than mysqli, also you can mysqli_real_escape_string() at minimum

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include "../includes/config.php";


    $current_pwd=$_GET['current_pwd'];
    $aid=$_SESSION['aid'];
    $current_pwd = $mysqli->real_escape_string($current_pwd);

    $r=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE aid='$aid' and password='$current_pwd' ");
    $row=$r->fetch_assoc();

    if($current_pwd==$row['password'])
    {
        echo "Password Is Correct";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Password Is Incorrect";
    }
```